# How to run Android-x86 4.2 iso on VM VirtualBox?

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86, iso-image

I want to use `Android-x86` to test and debug my App.I tried other versions of Android-x86 before successfully,but there is an erroe in about android-x86-4.2.So I ask my question here because it may be happen for others:

I installed `oracle VM virtualBox` on Win7 32-Bit,then I downloaded [`android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso`](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso) from [Android-x86 - Porting Android to x86](http://www.android-x86.org/download).After I installed Android x86-4.2 on VirtualBox from iso and creating fake SD Card for it,I tried to run it,but when I started it I saw these lines in console:

> Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sda1
>
> ANDROID root@x86:/ #

And no thing else,even I waited more than 20 minutes and nothing happen!I tried that some times but result is the same.How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I asked same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/587429/how-to-run-android-x86-4-2-iso-on-vm-virtualbox) in [superuser](http://superuser.com) and I found the way to start it. The correct answer is:

> From the install/live CD, you just need to change the value of "androidboot.hardware" parameter
>   in the grub command from "Android_x86" to "x86". You can do this by
>   pressing "Tab" in the boot menu or by editing "isolinux.cfg" file on
>   the installation ISO Image.

If you installed Android-x86 on hard drive,you have to select desired boot option and press `e` to edit grub command.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the project [Android X86 - Porting Android to X86](http://www.android-x86.org/download). I see in the web, this emulator has a complex installation. I think, if you want to try a fast Android emulator and install easily, debug faster, you can try project [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/). It is easy to install it to Virtual Box by downloading the image file and import to Virtual Box .

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand of Linux (which it isn't a lot, but enough I'd say) you're logged in into the system and waiting for you to type some command. If I'm right, you should launch the **X server** but on an Android environment I don't really know how.

UPDATE:

For what I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-x86/kW8YE6_eXXU), it's just what I said: it boots and after that it prompts the command line. Two solutions that appear on the link are:

- Type **start**.
- Select **VESA option** before the boot process (I can't help you out in this one, because I don't have the .ISO to try right now).

Please, check them.

Comment: @AiriFenix Thank you,but I had tried both of them before,but result is the same.

Comment: Is there any error message, exception, warning or something that can serve us to point where could be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not any message,warning or ... .It seems that it is wait for command,but I do not know what it may be.

Comment: I see you found a solution. If it works, I believe you can mark it as an answer. Glad to see it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run android x86 on pc is to format a partition in ext3 format.Then install android on it.It will allow androidx86 to run easily.

Answer (score -1):

I have HP430 Laptop with win 7. I had the same problem. But I figured out the solution.

While booting the computer with win7  I entered BIOS menu. There was a option to optimize pc for virtualization.I selected it. After that every thing ran smooth.

Later I noticed in virtual box that, in system settings the acceleration type was VT-x AMD, Nested Paging,PAE/NX. This was different before optimization.

Hope this gives some idea.