# Mouse location missing in android x86 4.2 0121225 virtual box iso-image

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, android-x86, iso-image

i downloaded [android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso](http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso) and i opened it in my Oracle VM VirtualBox in Windows 8.1 that i have in my laptop.

After installation i boot ANDROID whithout a problem as [Stack Overflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221703/how-to-run-android-x86-4-2-iso-on-vm-virtualbox)

My problem is that:

Android recognises my pc as tablet and does not show me the mouse position. I have already check the Show touches and Pointer location but it shows me point location only if i press left-click.

What can i do to fix this and recognise my mouse and show it to me.
Thank in advance,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on emulator window click on Machine menu-> Select Disable mouse Integration submenu

It will show you mouse pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i do not use anymore the virtual box. I used one week ago android as a second OS (Android 4.0 amd brazos) and mouse worked perfect. Anyways i will accept the anwser.